# lightgallery was closing if put next in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, angular, lightgallery

When Play Video in Firefox browser and click to next light gallery has closed 
I used light gallery in angular component  and use every thing like documentation
i cant find any logical issue to this behavior

Answer (score 0):

I have found Micro library of hash behavior made issue with fire fox when you use angular component in SharePoint  , i tried to solve   but no new unfortunately so I delete this feature from my component

thanks is general